# Difference occurs when convert _variant_t to CString or displayed in ("%s") using _variant_t.bstrVal

Tags: c++, string, cstring, variant

I want to convert `_variant_t` to `CString`, and use this:

```
#define  VartToCStr(vart) (_variant_t(vart)).bstrVal
```

If I pass the value to `CString`, it just works ok, but to `CString::Format(_T("%s"))`, it doesn't work:

```
CString str = VartToCStr(properties[VL_INFO]);
CString str2;
str2.Format(_T("%s,"), VartToCStr(properties[VL_INFO]));
```

Result:

```
str: "ES1-SW1-SW3-..."
str2: "E"
```

Why?
Added:
(
`properties[VL_INFO]` is created by:

```
CString str = _T("ES1-SW1-SW3-...");
properties[VL_INFO] = CStrToVart(str);
```

where:

```
#define  CStrToVart(str) _variant_t(str)
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to use CString::SetString() instead of Format():

```
CString str2;
str2.SetString(VartToCStr(properties[VL_INFO]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a indirect way to convert it to cstring format

```
cstr= (LPCSTR)_bstr_t(variant);
```

this can work